# Persist data using Cube.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cube.js

I am using Cube.js for backend and React for frontend. 
Whenever I stop the cube.js server data gets lost(I have to make the charts again from scratch). Is there any way to persist the charts even if we stop the server?

Comment: Do you mean when server stops you lose your charts in generated dashboard-app?

Comment: Yes exactly that is what happening

Answer (score 0):

Cube.js is basically just a backend to perform analytical queries. However Cube.js Playground provides frontend application scaffolding generation using various templates. In case of dynamic dashboard template it provides GraphQL Apollo implementation that persists it to local storage for development purpose. You're responsible for providing production GraphQL backend.

You can learn on how to setup it here: https://react-dashboard.cube.dev/authentication-and-graph-ql-api.